# Accompanist Compose ViewPager BackEndException Gradle Implementation Error-> Exception during IR lowering

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, runtimeexception

Compose throws the ViewPager and throws a BackEndException. When I implement ViewPager, I get an error, but I don't know why.

[image]

```
const val VIEWPAGER = "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:${Versions.VIEWPAGER}"
const val VIEWPAGERINDICATE = "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:${Versions.VIEWPAGER}"
```

```
const val VIEWPAGER = "0.25.1"
```

If you add the following to gradle, I get an error.

Please help me.

Comment: You probably use version of accompanist that is incompatible with your compose version. Find compatible version in this table: https://github.com/google/accompanist#compose-versions

Comment: Do you have a separate module? Are you sure the following values exist in the build.gradle files?
```
android {
 ... 

    buildFeatures {
       compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
       kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion ''
       kotlinCompilerVersion ''
    }
}

```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck